# play multiple SpeakHere audio files

Tags: ios, voice-recording

By recording multiple snippets using filenames, I have **attempted** to record multiple separate short voice snippets in `SpeakHere`, I want to play them serially, separated by a set fixed interval of time between the starts of each snippet. I want the series of snippets to play in a loop forever, or until the user stops play.

My question is how do I alter `SpeakHere` to do so?

(I say "**attempted**" because I have not been able yet to run `SpeakHere` on my Mac Mini iPhone simulator. [That is the subject of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251919/speakhere-record-fails-on-iphone-6-0-simulator-on-mac-mini-with-os-10-7-5-and-is) and because [another question on the subject of multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011196/)  has not been answered, either.)

In `SpeakHereController.mm` is the following method definition for playing a recorded file. Notice the final `else` clause calls `player->StartQueue(false)`

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender
{
    if (player->IsRunning())
    {  [snip]
    }
    else
    {       
        OSStatus result = player->StartQueue(false);
        if (result == noErr)
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"playbackQueueResumed" object:self];
    }
}
```

Below is an excerpt from `SpeakHere` `AQPlayer.mm`

```
OSStatus AQPlayer::StartQueue(BOOL inResume)
{   
    // if we have a file but no queue, create one now
    if ((mQueue == NULL) && (mFilePath != NULL)) CreateQueueForFile(mFilePath);

    mIsDone = false;

    // if we are not resuming, we also should restart the file read index
    if (!inResume) {
        mCurrentPacket = 0;

        // prime the queue with some data before starting
        for (int i = 0; i < kNumberBuffers; ++i) {
            AQBufferCallback (this, mQueue, mBuffers[i]);           
        }
    }
    return AudioQueueStart(mQueue, NULL);
}
```

So, can the method `play`  and `AQPlayer::StartQueue` be used to play the multiple files,  how can the intervals be enforced, and how can the loop be repeated?

My adaptation of the code for the method 'record` is as follows, so you can see how the multiple files are being created.

```
- (IBAction)record:(id)sender
{
    if (recorder->IsRunning()) // If we are currently recording, stop and save the file.
    {
        [self stopRecord];
    }
    else // If we're not recording, start.
    {
        self.counter = self.counter + 1 ;   //Added *****
        btn_play.enabled = NO;  

        // Set the button's state to "stop"
        btn_record.title = @"Stop";

        // Start the recorder
        NSString *filename = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"recordedFile%d.caf",self.counter];
        // recorder->StartRecord(CFSTR("recordedFile.caf"));
        recorder->StartRecord((CFStringRef)filename);

        [self setFileDescriptionForFormat:recorder->DataFormat() withName:@"Recorded File"];

        // Hook the level meter up to the Audio Queue for the recorder
        [lvlMeter_in setAq: recorder->Queue()];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having spoken with a local "meetup" group on iOS I have learned that the easy solution to my question is to avoid `AudioQueues` and to instead use the "higher level" `AVAudioRecorder` and `AVAudioPlayer` from  `AVFoundation`.

I also found how to partially test my app on the simulator with my Mac Mini: by plugging in an Olympus audio recorder with USB to my Mini as an input "voice". This works as an alternative to the iSight which does not produce an input audio on the Mini.